# How to get different values with same name from xml with linq

Tags: c#, html, xml, linq

XML - Code:

```
<Store>
   <Products>
      <Product id="PROD01">
         <Title>Product 1</Title>
         <Description><![CDATA[Product <b>1</b> description]]></Description>
         <Image>prod01.gif</Image>
         <Specs>
            <Spec>Good computer</Spec>
            <Spec>Good display</Spec>
            <Spec>Latest version</Spec>
         </Specs>
         <Availability>same day</Availability>
      </Product>
      <Product id="PROD02">
         <Title>Product 2</Title>
         <Description><![CDATA[Product <b>2</b> description]]></Description>
         <Image>prod01.gif</Image>
         <Specs>
            <Spec>Good computer</Spec>
            <Spec>Soon available</Spec>
         </Specs>
         <Availability>next day</Availability>
      </Product>
   </Products>
</Store>
```

C# - Code:

```
public List<DetailList> GetDetails()
{
    DetailList d = new DetailList();
    List<DetailList> DetailLists = 
        (from product in xdocList.Descendants("Product")
        join detail in xdocDetail.Descendants("Product")
        on (string)product.Attribute("id") equals (string)detail.Attribute("id") 
        into outerProducts
        from outerProduct in outerProducts

        select new DetailList
        {
            Detail1 = (string)product.Attribute("id"),
            Detail2 = (string)product.Element("Title"),
            Detail3 = (string)product.Element("Description"),
            Detail4 = (string)product.Element("Image"),
            Detail5 = (string)outerProduct.Elements("Specs")
            Detail6 = (string)outerProduct.Element("Availability"),
            Detail7 = (string)product.Element("Price"),
        }).ToList();
    return DetailLists;
}
```

Output: Good computerGood displayLatest version

But wanted output is:

Good computer
Good display
Latest version

For output I used asp:repeater. I tried to add tags like < b r/> and much more, but cant'find my mistake, how to get Spec to three different strings, not only one string. How to achive that?

Comment: `For output I used asp:repeater.` I think you forgot to include that in your question.

Comment: What does `GetDetails.Count()` return?

Comment: it returned 14. But what is with it?

Comment: If you use this specific structure a lot, you might want to use `XmlSerializer` instead.

Comment: yes, tried, but that's not the case..

Comment: Instead of using a join use a GroupBy().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you are joing the nodes with self, but as per your XML it is not required. You can simply project the elements like this:-

```
public static List<DetailList> GetDetails(XDocument xdocList)
{
    DetailList d = new DetailList();
    List<DetailList> DetailLists = (from product in xdocList.Descendants("Product")
                                    select new DetailList
                                    {
                                        Detail1 = ((string)product.Attribute("id")),
                                        Detail2 = ((string)product.Element("Title")),
                                        Detail3 = ((string)product.Element("Description")),
                                        Detail4 = ((string)product.Element("Image")),
                                        Detail5 = product.Element("Specs")
                                                   .Elements("Spec")
                                                   .Select(x => (string)x).ToList(),
                                        Detail6 = ((string)product.Element("Availability")),
                                        Detail7 = ((string)product.Element("Price")),
                                     }).ToList();
            return DetailLists;
}
```

Since you need all the `Specs` separately, you should have a collection of string and not just string. So the *datatype* of property `Detail5` should be:-

```
List<string> or string[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Friend got solution from Rahul

```
Detail5 = String.Join("<br/>", outerProduct.Element("Specs").Elements("Spec").Select(x => (string)x).ToList()),
```

Thanks #Rahul Singh